# Applications in Elementary OS 6.0 AppStore fail to install

Tags: appcenter, release-odin

Attempts to install some apps (Thunderbird in these examples) from the AppCenter fail with:

```
Aborted due to failure (While trying to checkout 7898e3822e6f10310c8f2b6ae8aa630ed102eb1e3341c7e57e0aa9757987d2ea into /home/mg/.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08/.7898e3822e6f10310c8f2b6ae8aa630ed102eb1e3341c7e57e0aa9757987d2ea-7UOQA1: Opening content object f5177de959293d7382c1995623c8ef3a389e90e48c801a2c4ef4d1ff74e1b0c3: Couldn't find file object 'f5177de959293d7382c1995623c8ef3a389e90e48c801a2c4ef4d1ff74e1b0c3')
```

There's a similar error when attempting to install from flathub.org:

```
While trying to checkout 7898e3822e6f10310c8f2b6ae8aa630ed102eb1e3341c7e57e0aa9757987d2ea into /home/mg/.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08/.7898e3822e6f10310c8f2b6ae8aa630ed102eb1e3341c7e57e0aa9757987d2ea-4ERGA1: Opening content object f5177de959293d7382c1995623c8ef3a389e90e48c801a2c4ef4d1ff74e1b0c3: Couldn't find file object 'f5177de959293d7382c1995623c8ef3a389e90e48c801a2c4ef4d1ff74e1b0c3'
```

Krita also fails while Desktopius is successful. I'm left with installing (often old versions) from Synaptic.

Comment: Ran the command, 'flatpak repair --user' with no change, either before or after logging out and back in. In the meantime, I investigated further and found that attempting to install from flathub has the same result. Another Flatpak issue I'm having is that it's not updating correctly. When I run the updates to the system, they're all installed except: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VapYE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VapYE.png) The Flatpak runtime hasn't updated for months, maybe since the initial installation last summer. Suggestions are appreciated. For now, Syn

Answer (score 1):

Generally when this happens there's an error with the user profile in Flatpak. You can fix it via the Terminal like this:

```
flatpak repair --user
```

This will regenerate the necessary files and directories. From there you should be able to install software properly